# How can there be no working directory in git bare?

Tags: git, directory, working-directory

I'm reading from this article [here](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/shared-repositories-should-be-bare-repositories/) and don't understand how there is not working directory when you `git init --bare`. How can there be no working directory? Isn't that the directory where all your files reside? When you create a file in your repo doesn't that start a working directory anyway?

I also don't understand the 2nd bullet, which is:

> There is no .git directory created. Instead, the files normally in the
>   .git directory are placed in the top-level directory where the working
>   directory would normally be.

What is the purpose of not having a .git directory? How does this result in the author's example about the creator of a non-bare repo doing `git status` and seeing that

> git would find a different object database and give different results
>   for this run of git status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distinction between a bare and non-bare Git repository is misleading and can confuse newcomers.

> How can there be no working directory? Isn't that the directory where all your files reside?

No. Actually all the information (ie. all the data that form a git repository) is stored in the `.git/` folder that resides in your project's root directory (assuming it's a non-bare repo) and that is *all* Git itself needs to create a working directory.

The working directory does not hold any state regarding the repository (eg. branches, tags, commits) and technically is not a part of it (ie. it's not necessary). It's just there for a way for the programmer to edit the files.

It may help to understand that when you do a regular clone from a repository on, say, Github, the repository residing on Github's servers is a bare repository, but what you get is a non-bare repository.

Now onto your 2nd question.

> What is the purpose of not having a .git directory?

Think about this: *What is the purpose of a working directory in a git server?* The repositories stored in servers do not need the working directory, because noone is going to just SSH into a git server and directly edit the files there.

So the repository structure is simplified by keeping *only* what's necessary, which is the contents of the `.git/` directory. Furthermore the contents of the `.git/` directory are put in the project's root folder since there would be no much sense in keeping them in `.git/` since no other files are present in the root directory.

Comment: @jlei It's actually the project's root folder and is formed essentially from every file/directory that's tracked by git (besides `.git/`).

Comment: in regards to your comment about Github's repo being bare - if it's already bare, why would I ever use the -bare option if Github would do it for me? Would it only be if I'm sharing it through my local driver with others?

Comment: @jlei Yes, the bare repos are usually for servers or generally for *sharing* the repo. See [this](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) for an explanation.